# Create a list from string of strings

Tags: string, list

I am trying to create a list from 'string of strings'. I have some descriptions received as output from earlier config

'description Security Mgmt'
'description WLAN 700'
'description WLAN 701'
'description WLAN 702'

But now I need to iterate over it, but if i try, it iterates over single string and outputs the characters, but what I need is list of complete characters in single line.

```
    intf_desc_lst = []
    for x in intf_desc:
        intf_desc_lst.append(x)
    print(intf_desc_lst)
```

['d', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'u', 'r', 'i', 't', 'y', ' ', 'M', 'g', 'm', 't']

but i need output as

['description Security Mgmt'
'description WLAN 700'
'description WLAN 701'
'description WLAN 702']

With this I should be able to iterate over each item as index item, but not happening as of now.

Need suggestions on how to achieve the required output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use append(argument) function with string.

Example:

```
intf_desc_lst.append(intf_desc)
```

Comment: It gives answer as 

['description Security Mgmt']  
['description WLAN 700']  
['description WLAN 701']  
['description WLAN 702']  

but what I am looking at is 
['description Security Mgmt'  
'description WLAN 700'  
'description WLAN 701'  
'description WLAN 702']

Comment: what exactly is that intf_desc? If I know this I will be of better help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Was able to achieve the desired result by moving the empty list out of the outside for Loop. Once done, got the output as per required.